# 'Provide the answer as a function of N. You are not required to show the derivation process.' What should the answer be?

Tags: functions, algorithms, factorial

**The question(as an example)**

I have N cities and I need to find out how many paths does the circuit have.

**The problem**

For an assignment my teacher asked me to provide the answer as a function of N. Then he specified that I am not required to show the derivation process. What does it actually mean?

The answer should be:

a) n!-1

b) 19! -1 = 6,402,373,705,728,000

c) 18!

d) 18

Any suggestions?

Comment: b) looks nice. Choose b).

Comment: Only (a) depends on $n$ (Please don't use $n$ and $N$ for the same thing!) Thus, if the only thing you know is that your answer should depend on $n$ (rather than being constant!), and if you know for sure that one of the answers (a)-(d) is correct, choose (a). "You are not required to show the derivation process" means that you don't need to justify why (a) *is* the correct formula. (Disclaimer: The question is a bit unclear, as you have not provided the exact problem you are facing - it may be that the answer should *not* depend on $n$, in which case, forget what I wrote above.)

Comment: Not quite clear what is meant with "path". But if it means in which order the cities are visited, the answer should be $N!$ Even if symmetries are considered or the start point is irrelevant , I cannot make sense of the answer $N!-1$. Rather should it be a $(N-1)!$ or $(N-1)!/2$.